# Time to delete some tags?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[dreamforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dreamforce) was recently used on [How to migrate salesforce outlook configuration to another org using dreamfactory snapshot](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29725/how-to-migrate-salesforce-outlook-configuration-to-another-org-using-dreamfactor), probably the user thought it's closest match. Seeing that there are only 2 questions tagged with it - [kill it with fire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request)?

Actually there seem to be quite a lot rarely used tags that could be merged / deleted / marked as synonyms... https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags?page=19&tab=popular (currently it starts on page 19 out of 23 pages total).

What good is [type](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type)? Or [typahead](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typahead) (typeahead? I'd rename it to "autocomplete" or delete... Although it looks like the question is about specific library)?

[remote](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote) - remote what. VF remoting, remote objects (pilot), remotetk (mobile library), remote site settings... These things should have tags with dash I think?

[vf](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vf), [visualforcepage](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualforcepage) -> [visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualforce)?

[decrypt](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decrypt), [blobtopdf](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blobtopdf) - I'd delete it too :)

[cas](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cas) - what is this I don't even...

Comment: I spent a bit of time yesterday taking a look through the tags and suggesting some synonyms (where I can), and you're right there is a lot that needs clearing out. The one that I'd love to see go that isn't on your list is `salesforce-crm`.

Comment: We've had a topic about salesforce-crm, i've been trying to remove it out of questions,  but it appears almost unstoppable. I think mods can't remove it as long as questions are tagged with it.

Comment: Perhaps what would be more helpful than anything else would be to at least have minimal WIKI descriptions for each tag! I suspect `type` was originally intended for posts referring to questions about `Object Type`, particularly in the context of `Casting`, but who knows?

Comment: Samuel is right on with that salesforce-crm tag. I tried to do a burst of edits, and got through ~15 before losing steam. That would take a concentrated community effort to get done, so I definitely think its a good candidate for the ol' Trogdor burination

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Tags are auto-deleted on a scheduled basis if no questions reference them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71129) so even those who aren't empowered to make tag synonyms can remove bad tags by just editing the questions.

In cases where the tag is only used once and would almost certainly not be useful elsewhere I see no issue with editing to remove it. In fact, I did just that for [type](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type).

Comment: Very interesting. I will pay a bit more attention myself to one-question tags then as I browse in the future.. I used to be quite hot on visually checking tags on questions, but I think in the end (as Samuel has commented above) the tide felt unturnable and I faltered...!